# Short story where people can be teleoperated in order to have someone with more skill do something for them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This feels like something I would have read in the mid-1980s in *Analog* magazine, but I no longer have access to them.

In the story people can purchase implants that allow themselves to be teleoperated; I believe one of the examples is someone who is extremely shy and self-conscious who has a much more socially-adept operator take over in social gatherings.  IIRC the host is still conscious and mentally present, so they're still experiencing the situation, they just don't have to worry about bad missteps.  It's also possible for the remote operator to simply offer advice and encouragement instead of taking control.

The protagonist is one of the operators, and I think we see him help in a couple of situations for his clients.  The antagonist is a fellow operator, who, I believe is trying to mess up one of the protagonist's clients in order to steal his girlfriend or something like that.

At the climax of the story the protagonist's client is in a hostage situation (or something like that) with a criminal holding a gun on the client and his friends, and the antagonist swaps the input to the client.  Instead of the protagonist being in charge, suddenly the inputs are coming from a completely different operator.  But the day is saved because that operator was running another client doing ballet, and when the operator does a jeté the client ends up kicking the gun out of the criminal's hand.

The criminal is captured, the antagonist is exposed, everyone lives happily ever after.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was made into an episode of Black Mirror, or at least they had much the same theme, with a socially inept character being operated by a much suaver dude

Comment: (I say *Analog* because it seems insufficiently sciencey for *Asimov's* and it doesn't seem to fit any author whose collection I would have purchased in the 80s-90s, nor do I think I have any anthologies whose theme this would fit.  It also doesn't really seem like *Year's Best* material.  It could have been *F&SF*, but I only picked that up sporadically.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This story is ["The Guided Man"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57950) by L. Sprague de Camp.

Editorial blurb from original publication in [*Startling Stories*, October 1952](https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_v27n03_1952-10/page/n73/mode/2up):

> Have an important appointment coming up?
> Have to make a speech? Or make love?
> Telagog will pull you through the crisis . . .
>
> . . . by remote-control

Comment: Can you explain why this matches?

Comment: No doubt that';s the right story, but this site prefers more verbose answers.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to add some information. Hope you don't mind. Feel free to roll back my edit and do it your way.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.

Comment: @user14111 Thanks for the updates!  This has to be the story, but I have no idea where I read it.  I don't have either of the de Camp anthologies, and none of the [covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?57950) look familiar.  I must have borrowed one once, though, since I wouldn't have read *Startling* before I discovered them in IA just a few years ago...  (And it's definitely long enough my memory of the story is substantially different from the actual; I don't remember the nudist camp at all.)